# How to resolve the SSL Error assign key value in Odoo Controller

Tags: json, api, ssl, odoo, odoo-10

I'm facing an Odoo SSL error. The error is:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='12.123.12.12', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/logistics/filldetailsntf (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),))
```

I'm writing a controller and I was checking on it. I need to know also how to turn off /Bypass the SSL Certification Verification in this controller. I'm pasting the controller below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import http
import ssl
import requests
import json
from odoo.http import request
import urllib, urllib2
from odoo import report as odoo_report
import datetime
import pytz
import base64
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

url = 'https://12.123.12.12/api/logistics/filldetailsntf'
authentication = '129487521452XSDFG156235C6B353CD75QWERBVFGHJAA96AA99EDSJUITH7AAF65258F22871E7D415EB4A77CF7B4CB513A993680FC6053EAE6RT785YUIJ124'


class MyApi(http.Controller):

    @http.route("/my/post/api/path", url=url, auth="public", type='http', methods=['POST', 'GET'], csrf=False, cors='*',
                ssl=False, verify=False)
    def post_api_method(self, **kw):
        partners = request.env['import.logic'].sudo().search_read([('customer', '=', 'TRADING COMPANY')])
        print kw
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        body = {'results': {"shipmentType": "partners",
                            "shipperName": "Name",
                            "consigneeName": "*****",
                            "vslexparvlDate": "2019-03-05 05:55:13:000",
                            "vsldischlDate": "2019-04-02 05:55:13:000",
                            "docRecvByMailDate": "2019-03-05 05:55:13:000",
                            "orgDocRecvgDate": "2019-03-24 05:55:13:000",
                            "vesselArvlDate": "2019-03-19 05:55:13:000",
                            "bLAwbNumber": "*****",
                            "houseBL": "****",
                            "dischargingPort": "*****",
                            "landingPort": "*****",
                            "containerNumber": "*****",
                            "delOrderDate": "2019-03-29 05:55:13:000",
                            "delOrderNumber": "******",
                            "bayanNumber": "*****",
                            "bayanDate": "2019-03-30 05:55:13:000",
                            "containerType": "*****",
                            "dutyPaidDate": "2019-03-22 05:55:13:000",
                            "transportNTFTerminal": "***",
                            "transportDirCustomer": "***",
                            "demmurageDate": "2019-03-27 05:55:13:000",
                            "lastDetentionDate": "2019-03-27 05:55:13:000",
                            "eIRReturnToShipLine": "****",
                            "eventUpdateStatus": "Delivered"
                            }}
        response = requests.post(url, json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
        return response
```

This is the code I have written. I need to push the data from my odoo to this API first. While I was testing only I got this error. First I need to solve this ssl error and I need to assign the correct field on each and every key with my field value from inside of the `partner` which is mentioned in the code.

I'm using Odoo.sh, if anybody can please help me.

Comment: If you want to bypass, use `http` instead of `https`.
`url = 'http://12.123.12.12/api/logistics/filldetailsntf'`